Add custom parameters to all default events while keeping default params intact
According to the official documentation, you can add additional global parameters that will be attached to all events using the config tag:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/event-parameters?client_type=gtag#set-up-every-event
It looks like this:
gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX', {
  'page_title': 'Travel Destinations',
  'currency': 'USD'
});

This will add the page_title param to all events.
In my experience, however, when you do this, all default parameters (like source for example) are not sent in the event. In other words, it will send ONLY the page_title parameter and drop all the default ones.
Is that the expected behavior and what you have observed?
If so, is there a way to add additional parameters to all events?

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference#get
